# How to auto scroll the view in ios Frank to find a particular element?

Tags: ios, automation, native, frank

I am trying to automate an ios native app using Frank page which has a lot of text field. But i am not able to find a step which auto scroll the page under view until the element is find.
If the element is outside the view, frank is not able to fill that field. Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, when a text field becomes active, create a method with as a parameter the sender (a `UITextField *`), and scroll to its position through the `frame` property.

Comment: the field is active but not in simulator view. In that situation how to scroll until it gets the element?

Comment: With the didBeginEditing event connected to a method ;-)